# add HyperLink to <td> in table with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add an hyperlink to a `<td>` in a dynamic table?

I need the 1st `<td>` to be an hyperlink to a url + cell value.

Table dynamic creation :

```js
for (var i = 0; i < riskData.length; i++) {
  $("#grdDemo3").append("<tr><td>" + riskData[i].r_id +
    "</td><td>" + riskData[i].r_team + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Comment: What did you try? How does a [hyperlink look like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)?

Comment: And the problem is? Just add the markup for the link like you've done with the table row and the cells.

Comment: You should also HTML-encode the team name in case someone puts `<script>` tags or similar in their team name. Some approaches to do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124052/243245, or you could build the entities separately in jQuery and use .text() to set the team name etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < riskData.length; i++) {
   $("#grdDemo3").append("<tr><td><a href='https://a.com/"+riskData[i].r_id +"'>" +riskData[i].r_id + "</a></td><td>" + riskData[i].r_team + "</td></tr>");

 }
```

OR

```
for (var i = 0; i < riskData.length; i++) {
   $("#grdDemo3").append("<tr><td onclick='window.location.href=\"htts://a.com/"+riskData[i].r_id +"\"'>" +riskData[i].r_id + "</td><td>" + riskData[i].r_team + "</td></tr>");

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always add an anchor tag to td element and make it look like a whole table cell.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding: 12px;
}

table tr td a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.google.com/"><span>Some Text</span></a>
    </td>
    <td>some content
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      hello here </td>
    <td>some content
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.google.com/"><span>Some Text</span></a>
    </td>
    <td>some content
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.google.com/"><span>Some Text</span></a>
    </td>
    <td>some content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```